# 5 year old didn’t wanted his mother to touch

Tags: behavior, primary-schooler, development, communication, age-appropriate

Today I was shocked and angered at my almost 5 old son when he started crying when his mom was tickling him while she was lying on floor and he was standing next to her. Our son said

> I don’t like it.

And started crying loud. I got angered and shouted at him saying what is wrong with you?? If mom and dad play with you u don’t cry like that and told him he won’t go to his uncles room.

My wife said I was too harsh. I admit I was and I felt sorry but It reminded me of emotions when someone feel insecure of being touched as I was molested all my teenage. My anger was too much but I couldn’t control it coz I felt like something is up.

But I do not understand our son behaviour tonight and how can I find real reason behind it.

Comment: Your question had a lot of irrelevant information, so I removed it. Please read the [faq] and [ask] for more information on how to write concise questions. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed?  What additional information do you want?

Comment: Localhost: can you clarify, are you specifically asking to understand why your son did what he did (and whether that's a reasonable reaction on his part, and thus, whether your reaction was reasonable or not), or are you specifically interested in finding out whether there is an unstated reason (such as having been molested), or are you interested in both things? That might help to clarify this and perhaps get it reopened, for other answers to be added.

Answer (score 11):

It’s entirely normal to not like being tickled. My younger son doesn’t either, and it’s very important that we enable his agency in this. At that age there’s very little they control - but their body should absolutely be one of those things.  He isn’t saying he doesn’t like you or anything like that; he’s saying he doesn’t enjoy the feeling of being tickled.

Go apologize to your son, right now, and have a frank conversation about how it’s important that everyone respect others’ boundaries.